# Column not showing at product list page in magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, column alignment is disturbing at Product list page, cms page list, Order list etc...

I getting this type of issue in Magento 2.0.2 version.
Here is a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if a JavaScript error is thrown (which you might see in the console of your browser).

The error might look like this:

> TypeError: cols[(total - 2)] is undefined

This can be caused by errors in the admin js or if `Mod` Pagespeed is activated.

See this github ticket for reference in this case: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5196